# Draw JSON result in highchart

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I use this code for highchart and JSON handling:

```js
var json;
var quantity = [];
var nm = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "../Broken/index.php",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
      json = $.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(json);


      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var obj = json[i];
        for (var prop in obj) {
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop] !== null && !isNaN(obj[prop])) {
            obj[prop] = +obj[prop];
          }
        }
      }

      console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));

      console.log(json);

      for (var j in json) {
        quantity.push(json[j].OC)
      }

      console.log(quantity);

    },
  });

});


var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'column',
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 15,
      beta: 15,
      depth: 50,
      viewDistance: 25
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Broken OC weekly trend'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      depth: 25
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: quantity
  }]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Broken OC graph</title>
    <script src="../Broken/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Broken/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="../Broken/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br /><br />
    <div style="width:900px;">
      <div id="container" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This the index.php JSON result:

```json
[
  {"wk": "W30", "OC": "7"}, 
  {"wk": "W31", "OC": "4"}, 
  {"wk": "W32", "OC": "2"},
  {"wk": "W33", "OC": "4"},
  {"wk": "W34", "OC": "2"},
  {"wk": "W35", "OC": "4"},
  {"wk": "W36", "OC": "2"}
]
```

My question is:
How to draw the variable `quantity` with higchart?!
If I insert that variable to the `Data:` field nothing happen.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to convert `OC` like this `quantity.push( parseInt(json[j].OC) )`

Comment: Thx for your comment, but unfortunately it dosen't help. My array already contain numbers (not string), so the conversion dosen't changed the result (no any display in highchart). Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax` is asynchronous: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, so you create a chart with empty data array. You should create the chart when the data will be ready:

```
function getData() {
    var json = [
  {"wk": "W30", "OC": "7"}, 
  {"wk": "W31", "OC": "4"}, 
  {"wk": "W32", "OC": "2"},
  {"wk": "W33", "OC": "4"},
  {"wk": "W34", "OC": "2"},
  {"wk": "W35", "OC": "4"},
  {"wk": "W36", "OC": "2"}
]

    var quantity = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var obj = json[i];
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop] !== null && !isNaN(obj[prop])) {
                obj[prop] = +obj[prop];
            }
        }
    }


    for (var j in json) {
        quantity.push(json[j].OC)
    }

    createChart(quantity);
}

function createChart(quantity) {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        series: [{
            data: quantity
        }]
    });
}

getData();
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b1jecy4t/